# Is there a way to register to memory alarm of rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

My application just got freeze because the memory usage of rabbitmq exceeded its threshold.

I am using `pika` and `pyrabbit` as a python wrappers for handling channels and connections.
I wander if there is a way that my process will register to something and get a notification when that event occurs (and hopefully even a bit before it does).

Answer (score 0):

When using rabbitpy you can check if the [blocked](https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy/blob/109e44392785a6b0de5994cc2162352f73576756/rabbitpy/connection.py#L162) flag is set. This flag means that the connection is being blocked due to resource constraints (most likely due to low memory).

```
with rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f') as conn:
    print(conn.blocked)
```

e.g.

```
while conn.blocked:
    time.sleep(0.1)  # wait until connection is unblocked
```